# Realloc возвращает NULL

Tags: c

На вход поступает текстовый файл и неинициализированный элемент структуры типа char*. Realloc возвращает NULL, из-за чего это может происходить?

```
void create(FILE* file, char* element)
{
    if ((element = (char*)calloc(0, sizeof(char))) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stdout, "Ошибка выделения памяти!\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    int idx = -1;
    do
    {
        if (fscanf(file, "%c", (element + idx + 1)) != 1)
        {
            fprintf(stdout, "Ошибка считывания данных из файла!\n");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        printf("%d\n", sizeof(element));


        if ((element = (char*)realloc(element, idx + 3)) == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stdout, "Ошибка считывания данных из файла!\n");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        idx++;
    } while (*(element + idx) != '\n');

    *(element + idx) = '\0';

}
```

Comment: Вызывайте [perror](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html) и смотрите

Comment: Этот код не компилируется. Приведите пожалуйста минимальный самодостаточный пример программы с ошибкой.

Comment: 50% шансов что `calloc` возвращает NULL а не `realloc`. внимательно посмотрите и потом выделяйте память побольше , а не ноль байт. `calloc( 1 , sizeof(char))`

Comment: Программа пишет одинаковое сообщение по ошибке, что по `fscanf` что `realloc`. Как вы смогли определить, что проблема в `realloc`? 50% шансов, что просто не открыли файл. *Зачем пишете число восемь? (размер указателя)*

Comment: @alexglebe ```calloc``` не возвращал ```NULL```, но проблема действительно была в нем, спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы сами ответили на свой вопрос -

> **неинициализированный** элемент структуры типа `char*`

Т.е. вашему `realloc` поступает команда - измени-ка ты размер блока по некоторому "мусорному" адресу. А там и блока-то никакого нет... Вот он и пытается вам объяснить это доступным ему способом.